# How can I set the order of membership organisations in dropdown?

Tags: civimember

I've added multiple membership types. They are related to several organisations. When adding a membership, in the form, I must first choose for which organisation, and then the type of membership, both in dropdowns.

Can I define the order of the organisations in that dropdown ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Membership Types can be ordered at `civicrm/admin/member/membershipType` it seems like the Organizations are sorted alphabetically [here (CRM-6099)](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Member/Form/Membership.php#L531).

- You could rename the organisations to rearrange their alphabetical ordering. This is probably not realistic :)
- You could create a CiviCRM extension which implements [hook_civicrm_buildForm()](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_buildForm) and rearranges the options in the Organizations list.
- A patch to core could make the form respect the order defined at `civicrm/admin/member/membershipType` for the related Organizations also.